# Cannot store items in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I am quite new to Javascript and PWAs. I followed a tutorial and used the same code as was used there but I do not manage to store data in the IndexedDB.
I use the [idb-Wrapper](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) of Jake Archibald.

This is my Service Worker:

```
importScripts('/src/js/idb.js');

// here: code for installing and activating the sw


const db = idb.openDB('incidents-store', 1, {
    upgrade(db) {
        const store = db.createObjectStore('incidents', {
            keyPath: 'id',
            autoIncrement: true,
        });
        store.createIndex('id', 'id');
    },
}); 


self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    if (!(event.request.url.indexOf('http') === 0)) return;
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/incidents';
    if(event.request.url.indexOf(url) >= 0) {
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request)
                .then ( res => {
                    const clonedResponse = res.clone();
                    clonedResponse.json()
                        .then( data => {
                            for(let key in data)
                            {
                                db
                                    .then( dbIncidents => {
                                        let tx = dbIncidents.transaction(['incidents'], 'readwrite');
                                        let store = tx.objectStore('incidents');
                                        store.put(data[key]);
                                        return tx.done;
                                    })
                            }
                        })
                    return res;
                })
        )
    } else {// other code not important for my ask for help}
})
```

What happens is that the code does open the IndexedDB but does not store the items I try to put in there with "store.put(data[key]);". Although the data seems to be in the right format, when I print it to the console:
data[key] = {id: 6, date: "2021-01-25T23:00:00.000Z", time: "09:30:41", name: "Meltem"}. (It's a request to a database with auto incremented id's).

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a closer look at the documentation for the `idb` library: https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb

Almost of the methods are asynchronous and return a promise. This [documentation on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) should help, as should [this guidance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) on using `async`/`await` as an alternative to `.then()` chains when working with promises.

You'll have to customize your code to actually accomplish what you want, but it would basically take the structure of:

```js
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/idb/build/iife/index-min.js');

async function addToIDB(data) {
  // Assume that db is an already open IDB instance.
  // Tweak the transcation logic and other IDB operations as needed.
  for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
    const tx = db.transaction(['incidents'], 'readwrite');
    const store = tx.objectStore('incidents');
    await store.put(value);
    await tx.done;
  }
}

async function incidentResponse(request) {
  const response = await fetch(request);

  const clonedResponse = response.clone();
  const data = await clonedResponse.json();
  await addToIDB(data);

  return response;
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/incidents';
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(url)) {
    event.respondWith(
      incidentResponse(event.request)
    );
  }
});
```